# Обратиться к элементу в двумерном массиве

Tags: php, rest

Не знаю, правильно ли задаю вопрос, но все же попытаюсь спросить так, чтобы было понятно.
Через rest api получаю данные об транспорте: (пробег, координаты, время и т.д.)

Так задаю параметры, которые хочу получить на выходе

```
  $data = array(
    "objectId" => [599],
    "from" => $date1,
    "to" => $date2,
    "tzId" => ["Europe","Moscow"],
    "scode" => "YDX",
    "sort" => "name",
    "properties" => ["extId","name","groups","carId","model","type"],
    "params" => ["moveStart","moveStartPlace","moveEnd","moveEndPlace","moveTime","parkTime","avgSpeed","consum100km","consum1h"]
```

Так вывожу

```
printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($result, true));
```

На выходе получаю примерно следующее

```
stdClass Object
[footer] => stdClass Object
    (
        [599] => stdClass Object
            (
                [distance] => 24.1
                [fullTime] => 86400
                [avgSpeed] => 19.35
                [consum1h] => 0
                [consum100km] => 0
                [moveTime] => 4484
                [parkTime] => 81916
                [moveStart] => 1551423762
                [moveEnd] => 1551436465
                [moveStartPlaceLat] => ...
                [moveStartPlaceLon] => ...
                [moveStartPlace] => 
                [moveStartPlaceGeoId] => 25046
                [moveEndPlaceLat] => ...
                [moveEndPlaceLon] => ...
                [moveEndPlace] => 
                [moveEndPlaceGeoId] => 153329
            )

    )

[header] => stdClass Object
    (
        [sd] => 1551398400
        [ed] => 1551484800
        [tzMin] => 0
        [tzId] => GMT
        [keyOrder] => Array
            (
                [0] => 599
            )

    )
```

И так далее...

Допустим я хочу обратиться только к "footer", пишу так:

```
printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($result -> footer, true));
```

А если я хочу обратиться к значению distance в footer, то как мне нужно это делать?

Comment: `$result -> footer -> {599} -> distance`

Comment: printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($result -> footer -> {599} -> distance, true));
Сработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как в объекте `$result -> footer` нужное свойство хранится во вложенном объекте в свойстве с названием `599` (я так понимаю что вы знаете запрашиваемый ИД - 599), поэтому надо использовать фигурный синтаксис для получения доступа к свойствам с нестандартным названием:

```
echo $result -> footer -> {599} -> distance;
```

Comment: Запомню. Я пробовал такой же вариант, но только с квадратными скобочками, стыдно, что сразу не догадался.